# Facebook permissions on react-native not working

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have ask to faceboook to have permissions of `user_birthday` and `user_likes`. It is approved by **facebook** and I have added these permissions on my **facebook** login on `react-native`

like that :

```
onLogin = async () => {
    try {
        this.setState({
            animating: true,
            error: null
        });
        const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_likes']);
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            throw new Error('Please sign in before continue');
        }
        const tokenData = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        const token = tokenData.accessToken.toString();
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
        const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
        this.setState({
            animating: false,
            error: null
        });
        console.log(user)
        this.props.loginSuccess(user);
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({
            animating: false,
            error: error.message
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is all work fine (on facebook login, facebook say 2 news permissions added  on my app for acceptation). But on my `console.log(user)` I don't see user `birth_date` and `user_likes` I have only into `providerData` the basic information.

**PS: I use react-native-fbsdk**

**PS2 if i add :**

```
alert('Login success with permissions: '
 +result.grantedPermissions.toString());
```

He say :

```
Login success with permissions: public_profile,user_birthday,email,user_likes
```

Comment: have you tried with different users? What if user has set privacy for this data?

Comment: Since Graph API v2.4, you need to explicitly ask for the fields you want in your requests. I don't see where you request the user details in the code above; if that happens implicitly with the SDK you are using, then it should be in its documentation somewhere how to ask for specific fields.